# What is the overarching category for Direct and Indirect Speech called in English?

Tags: grammar, terminology, indirect-speech

While terms like direct and indirect can be classified within a broader category (object, governance etc.), I am not sure how to classify direct and indirect speech. I thought it could be just speech, but found no evidence of that. What is the one-up here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct and indirect speech are subsumed under the term *reported speech*. Here is an extract from the entry on reported speech from the *Oxford Concise Dictionary of Linguistics* (p343):

> **Reported speech**: One utterance as reported by another ... . Strictly including cases of
>   both *indirect speech* and *direct speech*; often, however, used of
>   indirect speech specifically.

In language teaching in particular *reported speech* tends to be synonymous with *indirect speech* only.

Comment: This makes so much sense but at the same time it’s so weird… Thanks!

Comment: So, something can be reported speech and not reported speech at the same time. Why do we bother? I realise that my decision not to take A-Level English  language was inspired. ////// [Have you noticed that you're not the only S/shoe on the rack?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/427304/whats-another-word-for-ensuring-something-is-correct) Another source of confusion.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth. Well, we do usually come in pairs, although admittedly not of different sizes!